# How to implement different contextual-menus in a NSOutlineView

Tags: swift, nsoutlineview, custom-contextmenu

I have a view-based NSOutlineView and want to show different contextual menus if user right-clicks the header or one of the expanded items.

I dropped two NSMenu's to the storyboard file. When I connect the menu outlet of the HeaderCell to one of the menus I got an "Unsupported Configuration" warning and the menu is never shown. (The same warning for the Table View Cell)

I am using Swift.

Can somebody guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

1.Add NSMenu on your scene
2.Add Outlets setting to NSOutlineView then make relationship between NSOutlineView to NSMenu 
3.Add Custom Class which is overriding NSMenuDelegate